# Mysql Paging With multiple ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, offset, sql-limit

I have some issue with mysql pager.

- Count all rows is 164.
- pro_type - can be in 3 different integer values;
- pro - integer value;
- cr_date - some date.

Here is my queries:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE f1='1' AND f2='0' AND uid=43 ORDER BY pro_type DESC, pro DESC, cr_date DESC LIMIT 100;

SELECT id FROM table WHERE f1='1' AND f2='0' AND uid=43 ORDER BY pro_type DESC, pro DESC, cr_date DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 100;
```

- Second query result has duplicate rows from first query result.
- Both results do not contain one or few rows.
- The number of rows of the first query 100 and second is 64, so result count is ok.
- Query with limit 200 return all valid rows(164 not duplicated).

Maybe someone knows, what is the problem with ORDER BY & LIMIT OFFSET in that case?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT id `

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what is likely to be happening is that the data has duplicate values of `pro_type, pro, cr_date`.  When you use `order by` and the keys are the same, MySQL does not guarantee the ordering of results with the same key values.  In other words, the sort is not "stable".

Assuming that `id` is unique, the solution is simply to add it to the `order by` clause so the sort keys are unique:

```
ORDER BY pro_type DESC, pro DESC, cr_date DESC, ID
------------------------------------------------^
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: Thank you, now I'm understand. "cr_date DESC, ID" - solve a problem.